# jqgrid sorting column by text issue

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have used jqgrid in my site and am getting one problem here

**What I did:**

```
{name: 'type', index: 'type', width: 40, editable: true,edittype:"select",sorttype: "text", editoptions:{value:"1:Article;2:Seminar;3:Research;4:Cases"}},
```

now grid sort by id not by text for this column
so "Cases" appears at last due to its id 4

so how to sort this column by text?

Answer (score 2):

The most easy way to solve the problem would be usage of `sorttype` defined as function. You can create object or array which makes mapping of select value to the corresponding text and replace the select value to the text inside of `sorttype`. In the case the text returned by `sorttype` will be used during sorting instead of the value:

```
var typeMapping = {
        "1": "Article",
        "2": "Seminar",
        "3": "Research",
        "4": "Cases"
    };

...

{ name: 'type', width: 40, editable: true,
    edittype: "select", editoptions: {value: "1:Article;2:Seminar;3:Research;4:Cases"},
    sorttype: function (value) {
        return typeMapping[value];
    }}
```

[The corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ErKT.htm) uses the above code and it displays the following sorted results:

[image]