# jqgrid edittype select sorting column by label

Tags: jquery, json, sorting, jqgrid

I have the same problem Er.KT had here [jqgrid sorting column by text issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812569/jqgrid-sorting-column-by-text-issue?rq=1). I am getting json from my server and want to sort on the client side. My grid has `datatype:'json'` and `loadonce:true`.I tried to insert the sorttype function as suggested in the link above. Here the Code for the column.

```
{
  "name":"id_project",
  "index":"id_project",
  "editable":true,
  "sortable":true,
  "edittype":"select",
  "sorttype":"function (value) { return typeMapping[value]; }}",
  "formatter":"select",
  "editoptions":{"value":"2:Bike;15:Car;16:Aircraf;1:Boat"}
}
```

It still sorts by the options value and not by label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `sorttype` property should be a **function**. You use currently a **string** (`"sorttype":"..."`). If you try to load *all information* about `colModel` via Ajax request you should understand, that JSON don't support function datatype. So you there are no direct way to serialize function in JSON. What you can still do is usage *string* value of `sorttype`, but to replace the *name of the function (the string)* to the function in the same way like it's described in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5175127/315935).